# Better way to split one column into many, and then gather the results?

Tags: r, tidyr, magrittr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
message.id,sender,recipients
1,A,B|C
2,A,B
3,B,C|D|Q
```

I'd like to split the `recipients` column on "|" and then gather the results to produce this:

```
message.id,sender,recipient
1,A,B
1,A,C
2,A,B
3,B,C
3,B,D
3,B,Q
```

What's a clearer way of accomplishing this manipulation? Here's my current code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(message.id = c(1,2,3),
                 sender = c("A","A","B"),
                 recipients = c("B|C","B","C|D|Q"))

max.splits = df$recipients %>% str_count("\\|") %>% max + 1

df %>% separate(recipients,1:max.splits, sep = "\\|") %>%
  gather(trash,recipient,-message.id,-sender) %>%
  select(message.id, sender, recipient) %>%
  filter(recipient %>% is.na == FALSE) %>%
  arrange(message.id)
```

Comment: `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(df, "recipients", "|", "long")`, but I'm biased.

Comment: But you might be looking for something like `df %>% mutate(recipients = strsplit(as.character(recipients), "\\|")) %>% unnest(recipients)`....

Answer (score 4):

I'm biased, but I would suggest `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package.

Usage would simply be:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "recipients", "|", "long")
#    message.id sender recipients
# 1:          1      A          B
# 2:          1      A          C
# 3:          2      A          B
# 4:          3      B          C
# 5:          3      B          D
# 6:          3      B          Q
```

Alternatively, use a combination of "dplyr" for piping and "tidyr" for `unnest`, and then you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(recipients = as.character(recipients)) %>%         ## need character for strsplit
  mutate(recipients = strsplit(recipients, "|", TRUE)) %>%  ## Use `fixed = TRUE`
  unnest(recipients)                                        ## `unnest` goes to long form
# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# 
#   message.id sender recipients
#        (dbl) (fctr)      (chr)
# 1          1      A          B
# 2          1      A          C
# 3          2      A          B
# 4          3      B          C
# 5          3      B          D
# 6          3      B          Q
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(recipient=unlist(strsplit(recipients, '[|]'))),
              .(message.id, sender)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using `plyr`?

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(message.id), function(d){
    cbind(
        sender = as.character(d$sender), 
        recipients = strsplit(as.character(d$recipients), "\\|")[[1]]
    )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
df <- data.frame(message.id = 1:3, sender = c("A","A","B"),
recipients = c("B|C","B","C|D|Q"))
```

Original data

```
  message.id sender recipients
1          1      A        B|C
2          2      A          B
3          3      B      C|D|Q
```

Code

```
df %>% separate(recipients,into =c("r1","r2","r3")) %>% 
gather("sen","recipient",r1:r3) %>% select(-sen) %>% 
filter(!is.na(recipient))
```

Result

```
  message.id sender recipient
1          1      A         B
2          2      A         B
3          3      B         C
4          1      A         C
5          3      B         D
6          3      B         Q
```